# Custom move for VRP using Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I've been reading some SO posts and the OptaPlanner documentation but still not sure how exactly to implement the CustomMove and CustomMoveFactory.

My use case is vrp with pickup and delivery with time window. I started with the TWVRP example and made some modifications. I read the description of [PLANNER-833](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-833). I want to implement option B and create custom moves. I was thinking in my PlanningSolution I keep track of a pickup visit list and a delivery visit list. Each visit will have a reference to another so Pickup Visit<->Delivery Visit. I am having trouble implementing the ChangeMoveFactory. Is there any additional resource that touches on custom move for multiple variable changes?